# Restore WP 8 to another backup after it has been restored already?

Tags: 8.1, backup

I was using WP 8.1 from Developer Preview and used the Backup feature. After I had to send my phone in for repair I got it reset to 8.0. The initial setup wizard offered me a backup that was several months old (I guess the last one that was from 8.0), so I restored it to that backup. Now I updated it again to 8.1 and wondered if it is possible to restore it to the latest backup that I created just before I sent it in for repair?

Comment: Probably not, if you updated to 8.1 then backed up, that would be your most recent backup. You can only see the full list of backups for that device during setup.

Comment: I feared so... is it possible to "soft reset" the phone, so that the OS is still 8.1 but the data is deleted and the initial setup wizard is triggered? This way it should show the newer backup (if it has not already been overwritten)

Comment: You can do a soft reset by pressing and holding the Volume Down and Power buttons for 10 seconds.